# Convert Formulas to Values based on Row value

Tags: excel, vba, copy, rows, paste

[Work FIle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvTrq.png)

Hello,

I have spend days trying to figure out a solution and I have exhausted my knowledge. I would give my current code but there isn't one since all 500 didn't work.

I want to convert the formulas to values after they have been populated or by the row value P7W2 which changes every week and is located at C1. The values are located in Column D but I want to paste from columns E to Q based on the row value.

I don't think the copy and paste method work because it seems it has to paste in another place but I am just looking to convert these formulas to rows.

Can anyone provide insight into what is my best option?

Attempt 1

```
Public Sub CopyRows()
' Find the last row of data
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Loop through each row
For x = 2 To FinalRow
    ' Decide if to copy based on column D
    ThisValue = Cells(1, 3).Value
    If ThisValue = Range("D") Then
        Cells(x, 5).Resize(1, 18).copy
        Cells(ThisValue, 1).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    End If
Next x
```

End Sub

Attempt 2

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Worksheets("Item Class Data").Activate
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: tbh I don't understand what you want to do exactly but to remove the formulas while keeping the values of a range you just need to do `yourRange.Value = yourRange.Value`.

Comment: Yeah how do I get the yourrange.value to equal the row "P7W2".. I am thinking an activecell function that grabs the entire row and pastes values.

Comment: You either have to loop over the rows and if it matches your criteria, convert the formulas. Or, if they're sorted, find the first and last row and convert all the values in between. If the other cells are empty, as your picture suggests, you can just convert everything though?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct The file has live index match formulas that pulls data into the charts and what not. So when I update it weekly I need to paste the formulas as Values so each weeks data is kept historically.

Comment: please don't put that much code into a comment. Edit it into the question or start a new one if it's not concerning the original question any more.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Sorry for the inexperience, I posted the code from the two directions I was coming from. Neither work but I feel they both contain parts that will convert the rows matching C1 to values.

Comment: I slowly see what you mean^^ Here are some things for you to do: Learn about and use `Option Explicit`,  `PasteSpecial xlValues`, how to reference worksheets and cells. Then conquer the task step by step, not all at once. Oh and learn how to use the debugger, locals and immediate window. I am sure there are some guides out there.

Comment: Great, thank you for your help.